# Selenium webdriver: Programmatically sending keys

Tags: tabs, selenium-webdriver, keydown, sendkeys

I am looking for a way to use selenium web driver to mimic the user pressing the 'TAB' key three times one after the other and then the 'ENTER' key. I can't use keydown because requires a shift or other key.

I don't want to send these keys to an element, how do I mimic the user simply pressing these buttons?

I am using C# as my programming language.

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("<site-url>");
IWebElement ActionElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("locator-of-the-element"));
Actions builder  = new Actions(driver);
builder.MoveToElement(ActionElement).KeyDown(Keys.Tab).KeyUp(Keys.Tab).KeyDown(Keys.Tab).KeyUp(Keys.Tab).KeyDown(Keys.Tab).KeyUp(Keys.Tab).KeyDown(Keys.Enter).KeyUp(Keys.Enter).Build().Perform();
```

In case `Keys.Enter` doesn't work, try with `Keys.Return`.

Comment: That results in an exception: "key must be a modifier key (Keys.Shift, Keys.Control, or Keys.Alt)".